# error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: c++, qt, std, qmake, libstdc++

I am trying to install Qt in my CentOS system. While building the library, I'm getting this error:

```
/root/capture/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/bin/qmake: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
/root/capture/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/bin/qmake: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Comment: Looks like your 32-bit system is trying to load a 64-bit library.

Comment: "Looks like your 32-bit system is trying to load a 64-bit library." - No, a 32-bit binary is trying to load a 64 bit binary.  This could happen on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the softlink of the `libstdc++.so.6` has been changed and is pointing to `libstdc++.so.6.0.13` (64-bit?). I just changed the softlink by issuing the following command (in `/usr/lib` folder):

```
rm -f libstdc++.so.6
ln -s ./libstdc++.so.6.0.8 ./libstdc++.so.6
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem running binaries compiled with g++ under a 64bit ubuntu 14.04 installation.

I installed g++-multilib and everything runs fine now

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yum reinstall $(rpm -qa)
```

The above command will resolve all the issue in centos.