# How to manage libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 at computer cluster

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, libstdc++

I have a problem with the libstdc++.so.6 library when I execute a program in MATLAB. The code works fine on my laptop and my desktop, which is why I'm sure the problem is a library or linking compatibility issue:

/home/arturo/Virality/viral_cluster_ml/Viral_features/code/segment_pedro/segment: **error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64**

I've google some answers on how to fix the library, and some say that I should remove the library to later re-install the correct version:
[error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967661/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libstdc-so-6-wrong-elf-class-elfclass6)

The problem is that I can't afford the luxury to delete a library, because I am ssh'ing to a cluster at the lab I'm working in. I really wouldn't want to mess up any programs that are running at the cluster, so isn't there another way of fixing this problem? I'm hoping a solution similar to:

```
sudo apt-get install libstd++6
```

that doesn't require me to delete or modify any files, but rather to install them.

Or maybe the error is that I'm not linking the library correctly?

The file does exist, as when I use

```
locate  libstd++.so.6
```

the computer finds it at these directories:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012b/toolbox/sldv/sldv/polyspace-dvo/lib/x86-linux/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012b/toolbox/sldv/sldv/polyspace-dvo/lib/x86-linux/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a_DCS/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a_DCS/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/local/Matlab_R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/Matlab_R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/local/Matlab_R2012a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/Matlab_R2012a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/local/Matlab_R2012a/toolbox/sldv/sldv/polyspace-dvo/lib/x86-linux/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyc
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyo
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyc
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyo
```

I've also tried setting the path to the the file before running MATLAB, without anyluck:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/home/arturo/Virality/viral_cluster_ml/Viral_features/code/scene_sun ./matlab
```

Similar link and problem:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/apt-get-messed-up-812346/

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by recompiling a subfolder of the code on the cluster.

Comment: then please close the question