# node6: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: node.js, linux, suse

I have the above error and I've tried the solutions shown [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967661/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libstdc-so-6-wrong-elf-class-elfclass6) and [at this one](https://buildall.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/how-to-fix-error-libstdc-so-6-wrong-elf-class-elfclass64-after-installed-gcc-4-6/), that are pretty much the same, but both of them are for problems with gcc/g++, and not for problems with node.js.

I'm trying to set an environment so I can run the ***npm*** command cleanly on a SUSE 11 SP3 server.

Comment: Probably your node binary is a 32-bit one. Uninstall it and install a current node (we are now in 8.10.x, but probably you can download a 64-bit node 6, too).

Answer (score 0):

I meet this when I install npm packages in centos7.
That means your system is 64-bit system,and this package need 32-bit dynamic link library,you might need install **lib32z1**